# Mongoose default value if not exist in find

Tags: javascript, mongoose

we have added a new field to one Schema:

**First version:**

```
// Schema Definition Collection
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    IdUser: String,
    Name: String,
    Source: String        
    }
}, { collection: 'Image' });


const Image = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
module.exports = Image;
```

**New versión:**

```
// Schema Definition Collection
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    IdUser: String,
    Name: String,
    Source: String,
    Size: String        
    }
}, { collection: 'Image' });


const Image = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
module.exports = Image;
```

Later, in my Api with Express, we are returning the schema like this:

```
exports.getImageById = co(function* (req, res) {

  const image = yield Image.findById(req.params.id).exec();
  res.json(image);

});
```

In my jQuery ajax callback done, sometimes I have undefined in the field **Size**, but I would like to have other value (like for example 0kb) is the value is empty (not filled). Is this possible? Or do I need to check if Size field *typeof* is different to "undefined"?

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding `image.Size = image.Size? image.Size : "0kb"` just before `res.json(image);` ?

Comment: This is a good option... but if tomorrow we add other new field, we need to check another field again... maybe something automatic? Is this solution a performance problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @TalhaAwan this solutions is not working... always true... thanks!

Comment: It's just one object you're finding so performance is not a problem. This was just a workaround if you don't want to update the database but @andresk's answer is the better solution I'd say.

Comment: Your solution is ok, if I add .lean() to my query!! ;) Maybe, for performance, is better check typeof is equal to undefined in client javascript... But I can't update 3M of documents...